# Kendo Grid keyboard navigation

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Lets say I have a list of 1000 items and I am trying to navigate through the grid using keyboard arrows UP/DOWN.When I reach the last item on the page the keyboard DOWN arrow doesn't load the next items in the grid. [This](http://dojo.telerik.com/ayegE) is the code.

Thanks

Comment: I think there is no such functionality in Kendo UI Grid. You need to code it yourself.

Comment: I believe this may be a bug. Why won't you report it in the Telerik's forums?